# Applying simple function via across within nested data on each group

Tags: r, nested, dplyr, tibble

## Background

Given [nested data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html), I would like to apply a simple function using [`across`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/) on an arbitrary selection of columns. Using `across` I want to iterate over the selection of columns passed to one argument of the function and keep the second argument constant.

---

## Example

```
# Using across within nested data frame

# Gapminder data from gapminder package
library("tidyverse")
data("gapminder", package = "gapminder")

# Sample function
sample_function <- function(.data, var_a, var_b) {
    var_a <- enquo(var_a)
    var_b <- enquo(var_b)
    .data %>%
        mutate(some_res = log(!!var_a) + !!var_b) %>%
        pull(some_res)
}


# Basic example, not working
gapminder %>%
    group_by(country, continent) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(sample_res = map(
        .x = data,
        .f = across(
            .cols = vars(year, lifeExp, pop),
            .fns = ~ sample_function(var_a = .x),
            var_b = gdpPercap
        )
    )) %>%
    unnest(sample_res)
```

The example fails with the following error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `sample_res`. x Must subset
>   columns with a valid subscript vector. x Subscript has the wrong type
>   `quosures`. ℹ It must be numeric or character. ℹ Input `sample_res` is
>   `map(...)`. ℹ The error occured in group 1: country = "Afghanistan",
>   continent = "Asia". Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error
>   occurred.

### Desired results

I can iterate over the selected columns always passing a different argument in `var_a`. In this case the values reflect `year`, `lifeExp` and `gdpPercap` variables.

```
gapminder %>%
    group_by(country, continent) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
        res_year = map(.x = data, 
                       .f = sample_function, var_a = year, var_b = gdpPercap),
        res_lifeExp = map(.x = data, 
                          .f = sample_function, var_a = lifeExp, 
                          var_b = gdpPercap),
        res_pop = map(.x = data, 
                      .f = sample_function, var_a = pop, var_b = gdpPercap)
    )
```

---

## Sought solution

The solution obtained in desired results is rather impractical and error-prone as forces new row for each variable. I would like to find a combination of using `across` and `map` so I can run different variations of the mapping function only by adding variables to `across`.

Comment: In the `across`, you are using `sample_function(var_a = .x)`, here, I suppose it is the value that is getting passed and not the column name

Comment: do you accept non tidy evaluation answers? It is really though to pass a tidy eval though the kind of loop that I am imagining

Comment: Inspired by @Brunos approach, I updated my answer below for one more approach using `nest_by`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Final update** (using `nest_by` & `across`)

Inspired by @Brunos answer, I revised my approach to use `nest_by` / `rowwise` instead of `map` (which is, I guess, the new recommended way of wrangling nested tibbles).

The result of my original answer can be easily reproduced using `nest_by`:

```
gapminder %>%
  nest_by(country, continent) %>%
  mutate(sample_res = list(transmute(data,
                                     across(c(year, lifeExp, pop),
                                            ~ sample_function(data, var_a = .x, var_b = gdpPercap))
  ))
  )
```

However, it returns *one* list-column containing `tibble`s. If the output were normal vectors we could just remove `sample_res = list()` and new columns would be added to your existing tibble. However, in this example the output of each new column is a list-column containing vectors. I have not managed to produce this output in one call to `mutate(across(...))`.

It is possible though to use `unnest` and then another call to `summarise(across(...))` to get the job done.

```
gapminder %>%
  nest_by(country, continent) %>%
  mutate(sample_res = list(transmute(data,
                             across(c(year, lifeExp, pop),
                                    ~ sample_function(data, var_a = .x, var_b = gdpPercap))
                      ))
         ) %>% 
  unnest(cols = sample_res) %>%
  summarise(across(c(year, lifeExp, pop), list, .names = "res_{col}"))
```

**Original answer** (using `group_by`, `nest`, `map` & `across`)

You misspecified `sample_function` in your `across` call. It should be

```
function(x) sample_function(.x, var_a = x, var_b = gdpPercap)
```

instead of

```
~ sample_function(var_a = .x),
                var_b = gdpPercap
```

Since you are nesting `map` and `mutate(across(...))`, I prefer to have at least one "normal" anonymous functions instead of the lamda `~` notation. Otherwise, things can get confusing with two `.x`s.

Further `across` should be called inside its own separate `mutate`.

This should work:

```r
library("tidyverse")
data("gapminder", package = "gapminder")

# Sample function
sample_function <- function(.data, var_a, var_b) {
  var_a <- enquo(var_a)
  var_b <- enquo(var_b)

  .data %>%
    mutate(some_res = log(!!var_a) + !!var_b) %>%
    pull(some_res)
}

gapminder %>%
  group_by(country, continent) %>%
  nest() %>%  
  mutate(sample_res = map(
    data,
    ~ mutate(.x, across(c(year, lifeExp, pop),
                       function(x) { 
                         sample_function(.x, var_a = x, var_b = gdpPercap)
                        }
                       )
    )
   )
  )
#> # A tibble: 142 x 4
#> # Groups:   country, continent [142]
#>    country     continent data              sample_res       
#>    <fct>       <fct>     <list>            <list>           
#>  1 Afghanistan Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  2 Albania     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  3 Algeria     Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  4 Angola      Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  5 Argentina   Americas  <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  6 Australia   Oceania   <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  7 Austria     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  8 Bahrain     Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  9 Bangladesh  Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#> 10 Belgium     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#> # … with 132 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

When using `map` with custom functions to loop over `tibbles` in a list-column it is quite helpful to build a first version outside of the loop.

```r
test_dat <- gapminder %>%
  nest_by(country, continent) 

test_dat$data[[1]] %>% 
  mutate(across(
    c(year, lifeExp, pop),
    ~ sample_function(test_dat$data[[1]], var_a = .x, var_b = gdpPercap)
    )
    )
```

Once this works, then the final  step is to replace the object you want to loop over with `.x`.

**Another approach** (part of original answer)

Another approach would be to rewrite your original `sample_function` and include `across` in your `mutate` call there. We could make it take a string vector of variable names that will be passed to `across`. I might like this approach more, because its more flexible. Now you could have another list-column containing different variable names for different subsets of your data and loop over them and your data column with `map2`.

```r
library("tidyverse")
data("gapminder", package = "gapminder")

sample_function2 <- function(.data, .vars, var_b) {
  .vars <- syms(.vars)
  var_b <- enquo(var_b)

  .data %>%
    mutate(across(c(!!!.vars), function(y) log(y) + !!var_b))
}


gapminder %>%
  group_by(country, continent) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(sample_res = map(
    data,
    ~ sample_function2(.x,
                       .vars = c("year", "lifeExp", "pop"),
                       var_b = gdpPercap)
  )
  )

#> # A tibble: 142 x 4
#> # Groups:   country, continent [142]
#>    country     continent data              sample_res       
#>    <fct>       <fct>     <list>            <list>           
#>  1 Afghanistan Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  2 Albania     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  3 Algeria     Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  4 Angola      Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  5 Argentina   Americas  <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  6 Australia   Oceania   <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  7 Austria     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  8 Bahrain     Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  9 Bangladesh  Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#> 10 Belgium     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <tibble [12 × 4]>
#> # … with 132 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Add on** (to original answer)

As @Bruno points out that the approaches above are not in the format specified by the OP, here is an alternative solution building on my second approach above, which should yield the desired output.

```r
library("tidyverse")
data("gapminder", package = "gapminder")

sample_function2 <- function(.data, .vars, var_b) {
  .vars <- syms(.vars)
  var_b <- enquo(var_b)

  .data %>%
    transmute(across(c(!!!.vars), function(y) log(y) + !!var_b)) %>% 
    unlist()

}

my_vars <- c("year", "lifeExp", "pop")

gapminder %>%
  group_by(country, continent) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  crossing(vars = my_vars) %>% 
  mutate(sample_res = map2(
    data,
    vars, 
    ~ sample_function2(.x,
                       .vars = .y,
                       var_b = gdpPercap)
  )
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = vars,
              names_prefix = "res_",
              values_from = sample_res) 

#> # A tibble: 142 x 6
#>    country     continent data              res_lifeExp res_pop    res_year  
#>    <fct>       <fct>     <list>            <list>      <list>     <list>    
#>  1 Afghanistan Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#>  2 Albania     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#>  3 Algeria     Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#>  4 Angola      Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#>  5 Argentina   Americas  <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#>  6 Australia   Oceania   <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#>  7 Austria     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#>  8 Bahrain     Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#>  9 Bangladesh  Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#> 10 Belgium     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <dbl [12]>  <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#> # … with 132 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I don't think that this is the right answer, ideally there would be 3 extra columns like the example answer

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that the desired output is three different columns. Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, not fancy but gets the job done

```
library("tidyverse")
data("gapminder", package = "gapminder")

# Sample function

sample_function <- function(.data,vars_a,var_b){
  var_b <- rlang::parse_expr(var_b)

  for (i in vars_a) {

    namer <- paste0("res_",i)
    var_a <- rlang::parse_expr(i)
    .data <- .data %>%
      mutate(!!namer := log(!!var_a) + !!var_b)
  }
  .data


}
sample_function(gapminder,c("year","lifeExp","pop"),"gdpPercap")


gapminder %>% 
  nest_by(country,continent) %>% 
  mutate(result = list(sample_function(data,c("year","lifeExp","pop"),"gdpPercap")))
```

Here is the slower tidy way

```
tidy_sample_function <- function(.data,vars_a,var_b){

  vars_a <- .data %>% 
    select({{vars_a}}) %>% 
    names()

  for (i in vars_a) {

    namer <- paste0("res_",i)
    var_a <- rlang::parse_expr(i)
    .data <- .data %>%
      mutate(!!namer := log(!!var_a) + {{var_b}})
  }
  .data


}

gapminder %>% 
  nest_by(country,continent) %>% 
  mutate(result = list(tidy_sample_function(data,c(year,lifeExp,pop),gdpPercap)))
```